# stop "npm install" at [..................] | idealTree:regal: sill idealTree buildDeps

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

when I try to run

> npm install

it stop at this error

```
[..................] | idealTree:regal: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

I have tried for fix it for a long time and I tried several ways but it was not work. PLZ help me if you are informed.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to resolve the same issue by setting the correct registry with:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Perhaps you set a different registry some time ago and forgot about it? This is what happened in my case

Comment: This solution help me. but is better with https

Comment: For me only only the http version works NOT the https:
`registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 5):

I installed the lates node version using `nvm install node`. Trying to install any package e.g. `npm install --global yarn` failed the same way you describe.

For me, downgrading node (in my case to `v16.2.0`) did the trick.

Using a MacBook Pro with M1 chip running macOS 12.2.1

Comment: Downgrading my nodejs installation in nvm worked for me. I had reinstalled node earlier and installed 17.7.1, which appears not to have worked.

Answer (score 4):

It can sometimes take a lot of time. Espicially if you aborted a prevous `npm install`.

I would recommend deleting your `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` again.

Comment: It is a new project. so there is no `node_modules` folder.

Comment: @sina Then initialize the project. `npm init -y`

Comment: Yes. I had to wait for about 15 minutes. Unfortunately the progress indicator stands still so you could think that it ran into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if there is `.npmrc` config file in your working dir ,

```
registry=http://example.com/repository/npm-group/
```

The above could override your registry local settings

Answer (score 0):

I just turn off the VPN and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

As I searched on the internet, I mostly found the issue would be related with VPN or your internet connection. `This is an underlying problem in your arch linux installation it seems. if the above curl command works, then npm should also work, but right now due to the problems with your ipv6 network you're getting the timeout instead. unfortunately not much we can do to help with that one, it'll be on you to figure out how to get your ipv6 stack working correctly.`

`a VPN was causing this issue, I disconnected and it ran just fine`

`change the registry will help, we should set registry manually since it's stucked. u have installed nrm already? wow, awesome ;) when u set the registry yourself, dont forget set it both if u use yarn: $ npm config set registry=xxx and $ yarn config set registry xxx`

Basically it's related with the internet connection.

Edit: Fixed after editing in npm edit config

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, the issue was caused by the corporate VPN (zScaler).

Answer (score 0):

Change your registry from 'https://registry.npm.taobao.org/' to 'https://registry.npmmirror.com/'. It works for me.

You can do it ether by editing the ~/.npmrc or running the 'npm config set' command.

My node version is v20.10.0. It also solved one other issue '@vue/runtime-dom missing for Vue 2'.

It seems that the taobao registry doesn't exist any more. I run the curl command and got the following output:

curl -v -k https://registry.npm.taobao.org/

Output is:

```
< HTTP/2 301
< server: Tengine
< date: Tue, 30 Jan 2024 01:49:35 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 262
< location: https://registry.npmmirror.com/

...
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI.</p>
<hr/>Powered by Tengine</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the nodejs using nvm to 16.0.0 was my great solution

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows, use the following commands to delete the folder and the two files.

```
# for Windows
rd /s /q "node_modules"
del package-lock.json
del -f yarn.lock

# ️ clean npm cache
npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

If you are on macOS or Linux, issue the following commands instead.

```
# for macOS or Linux
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
rm -f yarn.lock

# ️ clean npm cache
npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

If the issue persists, try to disable strict-ssl key validation.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

1. Uninstall your computer's Node.js and install the Node.js that is **Recommended for Most Users** (see screenshot):
   [image]

2. Go to command prompt
3. Input this: 'npm install firebase'
4. After that, input this: 'npm install -g firebase-tools'

> Step 4 is required if 'firebase login', etc. doesn't work.

**Explanation:**

-The current Node.js version that you have is incompatible with your computer settings.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstalling node and then installing node again worked for me...

But... it only worked when I did with nvm commands..

Hope that helps

Comment: would you please elaborate more and make your answer more indepth.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to run `npm init -y`
after that try again `npm start`,

Answer (score -1):

**I found the same problem using v18 of node.**

In my case I use `nvm` to control node versions.
The solution that worked for me was to downgrage node to v16, with:

1. `nvm install v16`
2. `nvm use v16`.

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score -2):

I've done every solution you see on this page or Google, also ping to registry.npmjs.org was fine but in the end, the problem was **solved by changing network**! that's it! I just hotspot mobile data and the problem