# npm install not working on windows. Possible proxy issue

Tags: windows, npm, proxy

Could somebody tell me a possible solution to this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOvIU.png)

Tried:
[stop "npm install" at [..................] | idealTree:regal: sill idealTree buildDeps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678583/stop-npm-install-at-idealtreeregal-sill-idealtree-bui)
[Npm install not completing. How do i fix the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100736/npm-install-not-completing-how-do-i-fix-the-problem)

Edit:Got it to work only with a vpn but still trying to figure out why it doesn’t work locally

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's a firewall defender issue or a firewall in general.
For npm to work you'll need both the paths to it through APPDATA and the executable itself to be excluded.

Sometimes it might even work with a downgrade but sometimes that might not be a solution.

Check also [this](https://gist.github.com/darvell/edbc758b11ea4dcd7226b7c9f1821196) script solution or do it manually.